# Formula to convert numbers to Time

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I need to convert numbers entered `0.00.000` representing minutes seconds milliseconds to the following Time format `0:00.000` using Microsoft Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)/(24*60)+MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,6)/86400
```

with formatting `m:ss.000`

Answer (score -2):

let suppose you have a number 11.4 in cell A1
U need to add Formula something like this 
`in cell B1`

`=A1/24` and press `ctrl+1` and set B1 cell format to custom and type `hh:mm AM/PM`

Comment: This is not working for I get a #value in the field. I'm converting 1.23.435 to 1:23.435